I recently learned the movie is titled "Dead Poets Society" and I have no idea why it's not "poet society". What's the difference?
That's part of the language that I always find challenging. What is the actual difference between "poets society" and "poet society"? To me, both mean the same.

Presumably because it's a society for admirers of 'dead poets' in the plural?

This example is maybe a bad choice, since the movie is about a club for people who like "dead poets," plural, not a club that a dead poet may join. Perhaps you're thinking more of "Why is it called a 'men's t-shirt,' when it will be presumably be worn by only one man at a time?"

It can't be the "Society of Dead Poets" because the society is composed of people who are all alive.

Of course, it's the society of dead poets, and the joiners can be alive but the ones read, dead.

There is also a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Poet_Society.

@Řídící which is the name of a musical band, inspired by the  "Dead Poets Society“ story and Robin Williams’ amazing acting.

Related: What would be correct "Businessman's club" or "Businessmen's club"? (regrettably closed).

@Mari-LouA Surprisingly, the band claims otherwise: that the moniker is not a reference to the beloved 1989 film Dead Poets Society.

@Řídící  The band (not a society) was formed in 2013, that their name is unrelated to movie title is coincidental... and we really want to believe them.

This question is similar to: When are attributive nouns plural?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. For attributives involving more than one orthographic word, 'Working Mens Club' is addressed at St Matthews Church vs St Matthew Church.

@EdwinAshworth I think that this question is subsumed under the earlier question you cited. So you can say they're similar. But that question has only one answer, which has been accepted by the OP and has as many as 27 votes. But it's not terribly helpful, much less definitive. So I'm not sure how this OP can learn anything from the earlier question and answer.

@JK2 the automatic duplicate CV reason is inadequate, in my view. But if a duplicate question has inadequate answers, the correct procedure is for those having what they see as better answers to add them there (the thread will be CV-ed to the front of the list) and CV the duplicate. If the asker of the new duplicate has sufficient rep, they can add a bonus there. And close the newer duplicate question.

@EdwinAshworth Wow, that sounds complicated. Problem is, the "correct" procedure is not usually something that actually happens. So it's more like a "bureaucratic" procedure than a "correct" one.

@JK2 The major trouble in not taking the trouble to follow recommended procedure is bloat and the inevitable lack of ease in searching. Considered incorrect according to SE directives (hence the duplicate CV). The 'But everybody does it ...' is of course unscholarly in such cases.

Compound nouns tend to be singular, for example:
a six-month gym subscription,  a subscription to the gym for six months;  a candle-lit dinner, even when two or more candles are lit; baby milk is formula milk for babies; a match box (also matchbox) is a box that contains matches; a car park (also spelled carpark) is a parking area for cars.  But sometimes a plural compound noun escapes through the net: children’s book, a book for children; the ladies’ room, a public restroom/toilet for women;  menswear are clothes for men; and the dead poets society, a type of club that holds talks, recitals etc., of/about (famous) dead poets.
[A [dead poets] society] is a group of people who share an interest in the works of poets who are not alive. Obviously, it cannot be a club made up of poets who have deceased, but if it were the case, it would probably have the possessive apostrophe: Dead poets' society—a society for dead poets.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
